# Play through Television

Tags: video, hdmi

I have a [Dell Inspiron 3520](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3520_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf) (Intel HM75 Express Chipset, Intel Integrated HD  Graphics) connected to an elderly Toshiba [Regza WLT66/67 television](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/172207/Toshiba-Wlt66-Series.html) by a HDMI 1 cable which worked perfectly with Windows. I have deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu desktop 20.04.

I am now getting sound through the TV but no picture except the red opening screen. The TV is turned on before the PC so the TV can be recognized as an HDMI device.

As a pensioner I am not very knowledgeable so wondered if anyone could resolve this for a computer Dummy?  Ah! I had no idea this was a new version. Should I uninstall it or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, have tried that. Dell and Ubuntu logo appear then give way to red screen.

Comment: I would not try to do this with an Ubuntu release two days old. When something goes amiss, had you chosen 18.04,many more folks would be able to answer than with a version just out of beta.